# Ordered key:value pairs of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, dictionary

I have a set of tabs, and a set of panels that open when the tab is clicked. In order to be able to act on the tab and associated panel simultaneously I want to store them together in an object, like so:

```
{ 
   tab : <div id='tab1' data-target='panel1'></div>
   tabPanel : <div id='panel1'></div>
}
```

I want to be able to access them by name so I store the name as a key to the object like so:

```
 var tabs =   {
       'panel1' : { 
           tab : <div id='tab1' data-target='panel1'></div>
           tabPanel : <div id='panel1'></div>
        },
       'panel2' : { 
           tab : <div id='tab2' data-target='panel2'></div>
           tabPanel : <div id='panel1'></div>
        },
    }
```

So now when someone clicks on `#tab1` I just call `tabs[e.data(target)]` to get both elements to act on.

Sometimes the action is to remove that tab (not sure yet if I remove from the set of objects) and thus I need to act on the next tab object (panel2) to make it the new active tab. However, you can't grab the "next" key in the tabs object, so I thought to replace the object of objects with an array of objects. If I do that though then I can no longer grab the set of DOM elements without looping through the array and checking the keys.

It seems like there isn't a correct solution but is there a better choice in terms of least amount of code and efficiency?

Comment: Also this is just a shortened example, the tabs aren't really numbered "tab1, tab2, etc." so I cant just iterate by this number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast solution could be store a reference to the next tab object in every tab, like:

```
var panel1 = { 
       tab : <div id='tab1' data-target='panel1'></div>
       tabPanel : <div id='panel1'></div>
    };

var panel2 = { 
       tab : <div id='tab2' data-target='panel2'></div>
       tabPanel : <div id='panel1'></div>
    };


panel1.next = panel2; 
//panel2.next = panel3 and so on...

var tabs = {
    'panel1' : panel1 , 'panel2' : panel2
};
```

Now you can access them by field name inside tabs and also grab the next one with the .next property.

However, this is some sort of ankward. Maybe you should find an indexed linked list implementation for javascript and use it. Or another type of hight level Collection.

Comment: I think a doubly linked list would be [preferable.](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/21/computer-science-in-javascript-doubly-linked-lists/)

Comment: Nice! this could work. In my actual implementation I'm setting up these objects dynamically by looping through members of a '.tab' class so I couldn't do it exactly like this, but I'm sure I could hook up a reference like that within the .each loop. I'll wait for some more opinions before I accept though.